# Return the sum of the count of two seperate tables PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to search through two separate tables for the `COUNT` of a particular value and return it from a function.

```
  FUNCTION check_parts
    (p_partno         IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    out_exists  NUMBER;
    sub_exists  NUMBER;
  BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO out_exists
    FROM outline_pn op
    WHERE op.outline_pn = p_partno
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM sub_pn sp
    WHERE sp.sub_assy_pn = p_partno;
--      SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS out_exists
--              FROM outline_pn op
--              WHERE op.outline_pn = p_partno) AS out_exists,
--              (SELECT COUNT(*) AS sub_exists
--              FROM sub_pn sp
--              WHERE sp.sub_assy_pn = p_partno) AS sub_exists


      RETURN (out_exists + sub_exists);
  END check_parts;
```

At first I naively thought that two individual `COUNT(*)` queries would work...it didn't.

How do I sum the values of two separate `COUNT` queries and return the result?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are selecting `AS` sub_exists in the commented out query rather than `INTO`; when you tried before, was that how you had it? If so, that sounds like your problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried both AS and INTO.  When I used INTO, it wouldn't compile and threw a 'PL/SQL: ORA-01744: inappropriate INTO' exception.  When I used AS, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @corporateWhore Any reason you do not want to use two separate queries?

Comment: @corporateWhore If your question is answered. Please accept an answer. Learn more here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to have it in one query, here is the option

```
  create FUNCTION check_parts
    (p_partno         IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    sum_exists  NUMBER;
  BEGIN

  select count(1) into sum_exists from (
    SELECT outline_pn
    FROM outline_pn op
    WHERE op.outline_pn = p_partno
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sub_assy_pn
    FROM sub_pn sp
    WHERE sp.sub_assy_pn = p_partno);


      RETURN (sum_exists);
  END check_parts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not find a reason to not to using two separate queries. And then you can return the sum of both. You can simply write something like this:

```
FUNCTION check_parts   
(p_partno         IN  VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
out_exists  NUMBER;
sub_exists  NUMBER;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO out_exists
FROM outline_pn op
WHERE op.outline_pn = p_partno;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO sub_exits
FROM sub_pn sp
WHERE sp.sub_assy_pn = p_partno;


RETURN (out_exists + sub_exists);
END check_parts;
```

Comment: I did that originally but decided to try a single query because I want to learn the language and thought it would be good practice.